# sort each line of RDD in pyspark

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am beginner in pyspark so I am unable to solve a problem.
I have a RDD as given below

```
results = [('alice', 'charlie'), ('charlie', 'alice'), ('charlie', 'doris'),('doris', 'charlie')]
result = sc.parallelize(result) 
result.collect()
[('charlie', 'doris'),
('charlie', 'alice'),
 ('doris', 'charlie'),
 ('alice', 'charlie')]
```

I would like to sort key , val for each line  and have o/p like this

```
[('charlie', 'doris'),
 ('alice', 'charlie'),
 ('charlie', 'doris'),
 ('alice', 'charlie')]
```

Comment: So what is the criteria of sorting here? Looks like it is swapping between ascending and descending order of strings.

Comment: @Bharath Sharma, Please look at the new edit. I have provided the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your list of tuples to list of lists, since tuples are immutable data types in python. After this, you can sort each nested lists(I have shown how to sort for your requirements). Then convert the nested lists to list of tuples.

```
level1= [('charlie', 'doris'),
('charlie', 'alice'),
('doris', 'charlie'),
('alice', 'charlie')]

#Convert tuple to list
level1 = map(list,level1) #Converting tuples to list of lists(nested lists)

level2=list((level1)) #Here we have list of lists.

#Sort elements of the nested list
Output = [sorted(x, key = lambda x:x[0]) for x in level2] 

#Convert the list of lists to list of tuples
nested_lst_of_tuples = [tuple(l) for l in Output]

print(nested_lst_of_tuples)
```

The above code gives an output of

```
[('charlie', 'doris'), ('alice', 'charlie'), ('charlie', 'doris'), ('alice', 'charlie')]
```

Comment: it should be sorted in acending order . Like 2 should come before 10. apple should come before banana. But it should be done in pyspark RDD.

Comment: Edited my answer, please let me know if you need more help on this.